# Function composition by Chain rule

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition, chain-rule

I need to calculate by chain rule the partial derivative of:

dz/du

dz/dv

dz/dw

at point (u,v,w)=(2,1,0) for z=x^2+xy^3, x=uv^2+w^3, y=u+ve^w

I don't know how to find the function composition.

Comment: dz/du = dz/dx * dx/ du + dz/dy * dy/du + ...

Comment: what is that? @JonathanWheeler

Comment: How you calculate chain rule

Comment: with Jacobian matrix and determinant @JonathanWheeler

Comment: I would just expand the whole mess out and then do the partials.

Answer (score 1):

I give you one example and leave the rest for you to practice on.

$z = x^2+xy^3, x=uv^2+w^3, y=u+ve^w\\
Note:\\
\hspace {9 mm} {\partial x \over \partial u} = v^2\\
\hspace{10 mm} {\partial x \over \partial v} = 2uv\\
\hspace{10 mm} {\partial x \over \partial w} = 3w^2\\
\hspace{10 mm} {\partial y \over \partial u} = 1\\
\hspace{10 mm} {\partial y \over \partial v} = e^w\\
\hspace{10 mm} {\partial y \over \partial w} = ve^w\\
$

$$\begin{align}
{\partial z \over \partial u} &= {\partial z \over \partial x}\cdot{\partial x \over \partial u} + {\partial z \over \partial y}\cdot{\partial y \over \partial u}\\
&=(2 x + y^3)(v^2) + 3xy^2(1)\hspace{2mm}\text{plugging in the parameters for x and y we get,}\\
&=[2(uv^2+w^3)+(u+ve^w)^3](v^2)+3(uv^2+w^3)(u+ve^w)^2\hspace{3mm}\text{now evaluate at (2,1,0)}\\
&=[2(2\cdot1^2+0^3)+(2+1e^0)^3]1^2+3(2\cdot1^2+0^3)(2+1\cdot e^0)^2\\
&=[2(2)+3^3]+3(2)(3)^2\\
&=31+54=85
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks @BenB got dz/dv=178 and dz/dw=54